# Combining Javascript and CSS into HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the link to the code I would like to combine (includes CSS, Javascript, HTML separately): http://jsfiddle.net/4tjv85zh/3/

Below is my attempt to combine it all into one HTML file. It was, unfortunately, unsuccessful, but I'm not sure why.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="chart" width="500" height="250">

<script src="http://smoothiecharts.org/smoothie.js">
var chart = new SmoothieChart({
    grid: {
      fillStyle: '#ffffff'
    },
    labels: {
      fillStyle: '#000000'
    },
    tooltip: true,
    timestampFormatter: SmoothieChart.timeFormatter
  }),
  
  timeSeries = new TimeSeries();
chart.addTimeSeries(timeSeries, {
  strokeStyle: 'blue',
  lineWidth: 1,
  fillStyle: 'rgba(0,128,255,0.30)'
});

chart.streamTo(document.getElementById('chart'), 100);

setInterval(function() {

  timeSeries.append(new Date().getTime(), Math.random() * 100);
}, 1000);

</script> 
<style> 

div.smoothie-chart-tooltip {
  background: #999;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: consolas;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is your script and style declared inside your canvas?

Comment: a `script` tag that includes a `src` requires that it be immediately followed by a closing tag. Any code afterwards needs to wrapped in an additional `script` tag. a.e. `<script src="lib.js"></script><script> ....other code </script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This combines them all into an html form and is working in fiddle try it:

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/bmd09ue2/2/)

```
<script src="http://smoothiecharts.org/smoothie.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
<style>
div.smoothie-chart-tooltip {
  background: #999;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: consolas;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  pointer-events: none;
}</style>
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: the link wasn't working before, so I copied and pasted your code to try and it didn't work. Now, the link seems to be working and same with the code.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd...Im on Chrome and this works on jsfiddle but not this other compiler : https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_script. Do you know why?

Comment: Works local I think w3school in this aren't seeing the reference to smoothie charts, best quess.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have any Javascript inside a `script` tag with the `src` attribute set. Also, your `script` and `style` tags should be in the `head` of your document, not inside a `canvas` tag.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x8wyzgke/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://smoothiecharts.org/smoothie.js">
</script>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
var chart = new SmoothieChart({
grid: {
  fillStyle: '#ffffff'
},
labels: {
  fillStyle: '#000000'
},
tooltip: true,
timestampFormatter: SmoothieChart.timeFormatter
}),

  timeSeries = new TimeSeries();
chart.addTimeSeries(timeSeries, {
strokeStyle: 'blue',
lineWidth: 1,
fillStyle: 'rgba(0,128,255,0.30)'
 });

chart.streamTo(document.getElementById('chart'), 100);

setInterval(function() {

  timeSeries.append(new Date().getTime(), Math.random() * 100);
}, 1000);
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="chart" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, but still, none of the compilers I have tried return the correct output

Answer (score -1):

Move `<script>` and `<style>` blocks outside of the `<canvas>`.

Place `<style>` inside `<head>`.
Place `<script>` at the bottom of the `<body>` (just before the closing `</body>` tag).